# Limit Javascript execution quantity +/-

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to adjust these scripts and limit the number of times they are executed.
Script 1:

```
<script>
      setTimeout(function(){
           $('.next-button').click();
        }, 3000);
</script>
```

Script 2:

```
<script>
     $('document').ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
           $('.next-button').click();
        }, 30000);
     });
</script>
```

Anyone can help?
Thanks

Comment: um, it clicks once so.....what is there to limit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to limit.

```
<script>
 var limit=10, exec=0;
 setTimeout(function(){
    if(exec<limit){
       exec++;
       $('.next-button').click();
 }}, 3000);
    
</script>
```